# Match beginning of character list

Tags: elixir

In IRC, to keep a connection alive, you have to reply to `PING`s with `PONG`s, so if a server sends you `PING :irc.whatever.com`, you have to send back `PONG :irc.whatever.com`, or the server will close your connection.

I am working with character lists because, (correct me if I'm wrong), that's what my TCP socket returns.

So my implementation of the check for a ping message, which attempts to return the server that I need for the pong, is:

`[?P, ?I, ?N, ?G, ?  ,?: | host] = msg`

This is in a clause in a `case` block. That question mark followed by a space looks super dodgy to me, but it works.

I tried stuff like `['PING :' | host] = msg`, but that didn't work. And I've looked in the docs but I didn't find a better way to match this. Is there a better way to match the beggining characters in a character list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `++` in the pattern for this:

```
iex(1)> 'PING :' ++ host = 'PING :irc.whatever.com'
'PING :irc.whatever.com'
iex(2)> host
'irc.whatever.com'
```

> I am working with character lists because, (correct me if I'm wrong), that's what my TCP socket returns.

If you're using :gen_tcp, you can make it return binaries instead of charlists by passing `:binary` in the options of `:gen_tcp.connect`. You can read more about it in the [docs](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_tcp.html#connect-3). Returning binaries will also be more efficient than charlists. If you do that, you can pattern match using `<>`:

```
iex(1)> "PING :" <> host = "PING :irc.whatever.com"
"PING :irc.whatever.com"
iex(2)> host
"irc.whatever.com"
```

> That question mark followed by a space looks super dodgy to me, but it works.

You don't need that anymore, but just fyi, you can use `?\s` instead of `?`. The compiler also throws a warning for `?`:

```
warning: found ? followed by codepoint 0x20 (space), please use \s instead
```